# How can I compute the cartesian product between two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cartesian-product

I have two numpy arrays: `alpha=[0,1]` and `beta=[2,3,4]`.
I want to combine them in order to create a new array of tuple which is the result of all possible combinations of the two previous arrays.

```
x= [(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)]
```

is there a function which in numpy package or i need to do it by my self? If i have to do it, which is the optimal way?

Comment: Does the order count?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools


alpha = np.array([0, 1])
beta = np.array([2, 3, 4])

x = list(itertools.product(alpha, beta))

print(x)
# [(0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alpha=[0,1]
beta=[2,3,4]

d = [(a, b) for a in alpha for b in beta] # The cartesian product

print(d)
```